# Structural analysis + thermal expansion using ANSYS static module

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, thermal-expansion

I am attempting to model a steel sample subjected to combined mechanical and thermal loading. The thermal loading can be quite elevated, where reduction in the elastic modulus will occur.

Does anyone know if ANSYS's static structural module automatically accounts for the reduction of stiffness?

Answer (score 2):

You can take  have to use temperature dependent material properties for the e-modulus and Poisson's ratio. This scan be achieved with ´MPTEMP' followed by ´MPDATA´. Linear interpolation is used by the software. Example with fictious values:

```
MPTEMP,1,     20,    100,   150,   400
MPDATA,EX,1,, 204e9, 197e9, 193e9, 178e9
```

There is also the option to input a polynomial of 4th degree, so you can fit the data with Scilab, Python or any other scientific software.

For more details please refer to the Ansys documentation.
Jet fuel can't melt steel beams.